# What's the efficient way to manipulate DOM in Angular2 using Renderer?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I noticed that Angular2 Renderer does not have API to extract data out of DOM such as textContent or innerHTML or getAttribute. Even `@ViewChild` holds a target element which you can alter the traditional way using JS DOM API but is not recommended for other environments such as WebWorker or Native Apps.

The following example is wrapping each word in a span. Am I doing it properly or can be improved?

```js
import {Component, Directive, OnInit, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Directive({
  selector: 'wrapper'
})
class WrapperDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _element: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var tElement = $(this._element.nativeElement);
    var DOM = '';

    tElement
      .text()
      .split(' ')
      .forEach(function(word) {
        if (word !== '') {
          DOM+= '<span>' + word + '</span>';
        }
      });

    tElement.html(DOM);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-app',
  template: `
    <wrapper>Lorem Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet</wrapper>
  `,
  directives: [WrapperDirective]
})
export class MyApp {

}
bootstrap(MyApp);
```

Comment: Take a look at this exampe https://github.com/ralfstx/angular2-renderer-example/blob/master/src/custom-renderer.ts